# How to start a existing mysql container in docker (toolbox)?

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I have a container (i'm using this container https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) which had started before, with ID 5f96e9570d1b1475a888d7a615acdd9a7715c1ed6f0c40900f2e9c1ab485c7cf, but now how can i restart it ? I tried this command but not work

```
$ docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=*Abcd1234 -d mysql:5.7
D:\CWindow10\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/mysql" is already in use by container "5f96e9570d1b1475a888d7a615acdd9a7715c1ed6f0c40900f2e9c1ab485c7cf". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'D:\CWindow10\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

If i delete the container and retype the command, will the old data still exist in new container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restart an existing container, simply run `docker start <container_name_or_id>`.

Regarding the data: docker uses the concept of [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to put data. For the mysql image, there's a section "Where to Store Data" on the docker hub site. If you don't manually declare where the image should go, docker will create one for you. If you want your data to be kept, the easiest way is to create a folder and tell the `docker run` command to map that volume. That way, you can still use it if you throw away your container.

Answer (score 1):

1. use this command to restart container `docker restart <CONTAINER>`
2. starting new container will not preserve your data unless you have mounted external volume and stored data on it. Have a look at this blog http://blog.arungupta.me/docker-mysql-persistence/

Comment: i can't still start it by using this command docker run --name mysql -v C:\Users\hkveg\Documents\Kitematic\mysql\var\lib\mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWO
RD=*Abcd1234 -d mysql:5.7

Comment: if you leave the volume part, are you able to start mysql container. by saying 'docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:5.7.22 '

Comment: The blog you shared is deprecated.